# didReceiveRemoteNotification not called when Firebase is used along with Push framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, apple-push-notifications

I am using `Firebase` for analytics and a library for push notifications. When I use either of them, **didReceiveRemoteNotification** get called. But when I use them both together, **didReceiveRemoteNotification** doesn't get called.
Code :

**didFinishLaunchingWithOptions** :

```
NSString *google_app_id = @"----";
    NSString *gcm_sender_id = @"----";
    FIROptions *o = [[FIROptions alloc] initWithGoogleAppID:google_app_id GCMSenderID:gcm_sender_id];
    o.APIKey = @"----";
    o.bundleID = @"----";
    o.clientID = @"----";
    [FIRApp configureWithOptions:o];  

// Initilization of push framework
```

**didReceiveRemoteNotification** :

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {
    // This method is not called when Firebase and push framework are enabled at the same time
    // It works fine when only Firebase or only push framework is enabled
    NSLog(@"Push: %@", userInfo);
}
```

Comment: How are you registering to receive push notifications?

Comment: @dudeman : The push framework does that. They have their backend. When the framework is initialised, push, app gets registered for push notifications.

Comment: After you register for push notifications, there are callback methods to let you know if the registration was successful or not, as well as provide you with a push token to use for sending notifications. Have you tried to see if registration is succeeding? Also, what are you doing with the token they give you?

Comment: @dudeman : Registration is definitely successful. I am receiving push notification always. It's just that with both push framework and Firebase, didReceiveRemoteNotification is not called.

Comment: Have you looked into the UNUserNotificationCenter https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenter

Comment: @dudeman : I did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because Firebase uses [swizzling](https://nshipster.com/method-swizzling/) to intercept methods of the AppDelegate.

You should disable it in your app's **info.plist**:

```
<key>FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled</key>
<false/>
```

Actually there is a lot of information about [Push Notification in iOS with Firebase](https://github.com/onmyway133/blog/issues/64)  on GitHub. You probably will find answers for your further questions there.

Comment: But that is stopping Firebase Analytics as well. Any way just to disable Firebase push notification ?

Comment: Does it disable entire analytics, or just some events? May be you can try to call them manually.

Comment: I require all analytics to be handled by Firebase, not manually.

Comment: @Nitish, you require it from me, sir? :D Sorry, I think I can't help. If I was you I would contact Firebase support or just handle those events manually.

Comment: That is not what I meant. But I understand your point. Thanks.

Comment: I understand that it wasn't what you meant, it was just a joke.

Answer (score -1):

In the documentation for this method in Firebase Cloud Messaging said:

> If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in
>   the background, this callback will not be fired till the user taps
>   on the notification launching the application.

mb this method calls only when you tapped on notification which launch app?

In my experience I deal with pushs with this methods:

```
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center
didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response
         withCompletionHandler:(void (^)())completionHandler {
```

Method get info about coming push notification if app is active. 
 In block you must put constant to show your notification:

```
completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptionAlert);
```

And another one:

```
(void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center
       willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification
         withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions))completionHandler {
```

This method works with tapping on push notification. Mb here you are working with moving to some special screen.

Hope my exp helps!